# How does a smart contract call a function of another smart contract that requires payment?

Tags: solidity

I can call functions of other smart contracts that don't require payment, I can send money to another smart contract, but how do make a smart contract call a function and pay another smart contract at the same time?

Here's a sample code to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

Smart contract 1 whose function I want to call:

```
function buyTicket() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 2 ether, "not enough ether");
        require(lotteryFunds >= 2 ether, "casino closed for lack of funding");
        tickets++;
    }
```

Smart contract 2 who is trying to call that function:

```
   function getTicket() private {
        require(address(this).balance >= 2 ether, "not enough in the contract");
        (bool success,) = payable(casino).call{value: 2 ether}("");
        require(success, "Fail at stage one");
        t.buyTicket();
    }
```

getTicket() (which is called by another function) returns "not enough ether".  I think this is because the function is first sending ether, then calling the function with 0 ether, which would return "not enough ether".  How do I call the function *with* the payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function buyTicket of the second contract while sending 2 eth

Here is an example:

```
contract Receiver {

    uint public tickets;

    function buyTicket() public payable {
            require(msg.value == 2 ether, "not enough ether");
            // require(lotteryFunds >= 2 ether, "casino closed for lack of funding");
            tickets++;
        }
}

contract Sender {

    Receiver public receiver;

    constructor(address payable _receiverAddress) payable {
        receiver = Receiver(_receiverAddress);
    }

    function getTicket() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= 2 ether, "Not sending enought");
        receiver.buyTicket{value: 2 ether}();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

P.s. I commanded out the lotteryFund require since I had no idea what it was.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a specific function of another smart contract you can use the [function selector](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/abi-spec.html?highlight=function%20selector#function-selector):

```
(bool success,) = payable(casino).call{value: 2 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature("buyTicket()"));
```